Azure data Factory - Remeve duplicate rows on one file using on more than one column
Within Azure data Factory data flow, I have one file with 4 columns, I want to remove all duplicate rows using data flow transformations
Example
First_name,Last_name,Email,phone
Steven,king,Steving@gma.com,222 
Steve,king,Steving@gma.com,666
Steven,king,sss@g.fr,222
Neena,kosh,NK@gm.com,555
Nina,kosh,Nk@gm.com,999
Neena,Kosh,knj@hotmail.fr,555

What I wanted :
First_name,Last_name,Email,phone
Steven,king,Steving@gma.com,222 
Neena,kosh,NK@gm.com,555

The rules is if First_name,Last_name,Email are the same
Or
First_name,Last_name,phone are the same: WE consider it like a duplicate records

If first and last name are same, which row should be deleted or considered as duplicate row?

In order to find duplicates in an ADF dataflow, you can use the Window transformation and apply the RowNumber() function for each group. Next, use the Filter transformation to remove all rows with row numbers other than 1. This will ensure that there are no duplicates. Below are the steps to achieve this:

Take the source data in the source transformation.
Take the window transformation and provide the columns to group in the over section.
Specify the column name in which the result data should be sorted and computed in the sort section.
Apply the aggregate function rownumber() in the window columns section for a new column named Rownumber.
Then take the filter transformation and give the condition as Rownumber==1.


For your case, you can use this approach twice, one to remove the duplicates for the group FirstName, LastName, Email and the other to remove the duplicates in the group FirstName,LastName,Phone.
